# JREPL.bat regex replacing inside quotes

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jrepl

Im using JREPL.BAT to find and replace  specific instances and my regex I have works for find and replace in VSC code and also in the couple regex editors I've used.

```
CALL ./framework/config/JREPL.BAT "(Error)+\(([^()]*|\(([^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\))*\)" "Error(\"\")" /f ./dist/index.html /o
```

so what I'm expecting is it to find any case of

```
Error("")
```

or

```
Error( skjdksjdskd() + "" + )
```

etc

Find and replace works perfectly but jrepl takes

```
Error( skjdksjdskd() + "" + )
```

and changes it to

```
Error()( skjdksjdskd() + "" + )
```

does anyone know with more JREPL experience know why its ignoring the quotes and also not replacing the () area?

Comment: Notice how your chosen JRepl options us a forward slash, _as opposed to a hyphen_? It would make sense therefore to use the correct Windows path separators along side them! `.\framework\config\JREPL.BAT` and `.\dist\index.html`

Comment: Granted Dave does visit StackOverFlow a lot but why not ask the question where he maintains the [JREPL](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JREPL is hybrid JScript/batch that uses CSCRIPT - the Windows script host.

CSCRIPT has an inherent limitation that prevents double quote literals from being passed as parameters - there is no CSCRIPT escape sequence that includes a `"` literal.

To include a `"` literal in your query string, you can use `\x22` instead. All of the standard JScript escape sequences can be used in the query string. By default, escape sequences are not recognized in the replace string.

But you want a quote literal in your replace string. This requires the `/XSEQ` option so you can use the JREPL extended escape sequence of `\q`. A significant advantage of this option is you can also use the extended escape sequences in the replace string. You could also use `\x22` for both the search and replace strings if you prefer, but I find `\q` much easier to remember.

You have one other potential problem - the CALL command doubles all quoted carets, so `[^()]` (any character other than `(` or `)`) becomes `[^^()]` (any character other than `^`, `(` or `)`). This is definitely not what you want. That is the reason I added the `\c` = `^` extended escape sequence.

So I believe the following will give your expected result:

```
CALL .\framework\config\JREPL.BAT "(Error)+\(([\c()]*|\(([\c()]*|\([\c()]*\))*\))*\)" "Error(\q\q)" /xseq /f .\dist\index.html /o -
```

FYI - The effect of the `^` beginning of string anchor is not harmed by caret doubling - you don't need the `\c` escape sequence for the beginning of string anchor because `"^MatchStringBeginning"` and `"^^MatchStringBeginning"` yield identical regex results.

You can get more information about the extended escape sequences by issuing `jrepl /?/xseq`, or `jrepl /??/xseq` for paged help.

```
>jrepl /?/xseq

      /XSEQ - Enables extended escape sequences for both Search strings and
            Replacement strings, with support for the following sequences:

            \\     -  Backslash
            \b     -  Backspace
            \c     -  Caret (^)
            \f     -  Formfeed
            \n     -  Newline
            \q     -  Quote (")
            \r     -  Carriage Return
            \t     -  Horizontal Tab
            \v     -  Vertical Tab
            \xnn   -  Extended ASCII byte code expressed as 2 hex digits nn.
                      The code is mapped to the correct Unicode code point,
                      depending on the chosen character set. If used within
                      a Find string, then the input character set is used. If
                      within a Replacement string, then the output character
                      set is used. If the selected character set is invalid or
                      not a single byte character set, then \xnn is treated as
                      a Unicode code point. Note that extended ASCII character
                      class ranges like [\xnn-\xnn] should not be used because
                      the intended range likely does not map to a contiguous
                      set of Unicode code points - use [\x{nn-mm}] instead.
            \x{nn-mm} - A range of extended ASCII byte codes for use within
                      a regular expression character class expression. The
                      The min value nn and max value mm are expressed as hex
                      digits. The range is automatically expanded into the
                      full set of mapped Unicode code points. The character
                      set mapping rules are the same as for \xnn.
            \x{nn,CharSet} - Same as \xnn, except explicitly uses CharSet
                      character set mapping.
            \x{nn-mm,CharSet} - Same as \x{nn-mm}, except explicitly uses
                      CharSet character set mapping.
            \unnnn -  Unicode code point expressed as 4 hex digits nnnn.
            \u{N}  -  Any Unicode code point where N is 1 to 6 hex digits

            JREPL automatically creates an XBYTES.DAT file containing all 256
            possible byte codes. The XBYTES.DAT file is preferentially created
            in "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\JREPL\" if at all possible. Otherwise the
            file is created in "%TEMP%\JREPL\" instead. JREPL uses the file
            to establish the correct \xnn byte code mapping for each character
            set. Once created, successive runs reuse the same XBYTES.DAT file.
            If the file gets corrupted, then use the /XBYTES option to force
            creation of a new XBYTES.DAT file. If JREPL cannot create the file
            for any reason, then JREPL silently defaults to using pre v7.4
            behavior where /XSEQ \xnn is interpreted as Windows-1252. Creation
            of XBYTES.DAT requires either CERTUTIL.EXE or ADO. It is possible
            that both may be missing from an XP machine.

            Without the /XSEQ option, only standard JSCRIPT escape sequences
            \\, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t, \v, \xnn, \unnnn are available for the
            search strings. And the \xnn sequence represents a unicode
            code point, not extended ASCII.

            Extended escape sequences are supported even when the /L option
            is used. Both Search and Replace support all of the extended
            escape sequences if both the /XSEQ and /L options are combined.

            Extended escape sequences are not applied to JScript code when
            using any of the /Jxxx options. Use the decode() function if
            extended escape sequences are needed within the code.
```

Final Answer for this is to escape the quotes and backslashes as `\"` AND `\\` when using CALL in Webpack-shell-plugin.

```
'call "./framework/config/JREPL.BAT" \"(Error)\\(([\\c()]*|\\(([\\c()]*|\\([\\c()]*\\))*\\))*\\)\" \"Error(\\q\\q)\" /xseq /f ./dist/index.html /o ./dist/indexFinal.html'
```

Comment: Im getting this result with your answer.

```new Error(qq)"cannot override final property '"+a+"', set Class.ignoreFinals = true to skip")```

Comment: @DerekLawrence - Not sure why it isn't working for you. I created a text file with your example line and ran the JREPL command I provided, and it worked perfectly. Please edit your question to include a few lines of the source file that are having the problem. I suspect  you have a problem with your find regex and/or possibly you have an encoding issue with your source file. JREPL can support nearly any encoding - use `jrepl /?/f` for more information.

Comment: Dave, I think we need to SO tag for JREPL.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, encodign is utf-8 on the file. Also could it be that im running it using ```WebpackShellPlugin``` ```var webpackShellPlugin = new WebpackShellPlugin({
    onBuildEnd: [
        'CALL ./framework/config/JREPL.BAT "(Error)+\(([\c()]*|\(([\c()]*|\([\c()]*\))*\))*\)" "Error(\q\q)" /xseq /f ./dist/index.html /o ./dist/indexFinal.html',
    ]
});```

Comment: @DerekLawrence - That could be the problem - I don't know anything about WebpackShellPlugin. I'm wondering if the `]` in your find string are causing issues with the WebpackShellPlugin syntax. I also wonder if that plugin has its own escape layer, perhaps all `\` must be `\\` in your case.

Comment: @DerekLawrence - The utf-8 encoding shouldn't be causing the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: @Squashman - I was just thinking the same thing. I may create one

Comment: Okay yeah ti works perfect when calling from cmdline manually, seems the issue os somewhere with webpackshellPlugin

Comment: Which is weird because it replaces part of it but not the second part. Its like the formatting is different

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I figured out the issue was it was escaping all the `\` before passing it to JREPL. So escaping the escaping \ was needed as well as on the q's and then removing the \c for some reason makes it work. ```'call "./framework/config/JREPL.BAT" \"(Error)\\(([\\c()]*|\\(([\\c()]*|\\([\\c()]*\\))*\\))*\\)\" \"Error(\\q\\q)\" /xseq /f ./dist/index.html /o ./dist/indexFinal.html',```